# How to align the header of the PDF to the center in jspdf-autotable?

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have to place the heading of the pdf in the center. I have tried many ways but could not find a possible way that worked.

I am using the jspdf and jspdf-autotable package to form the pdf using reactjs.

```
var options = {
  didDrawPage: function (data) {
            // Header
            doc.text(heading, 20, 10,{
                    halign: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle'
                });
        }
};
doc.autoTable(columns, rows, options);
doc.save('table.pdf');
```

The above code is not working for me.

Answer (score 5):

To align specific header column:

- you must add column name in head definition
- add function to hook `didParseCell`

```js
const head = [
    {
        code: 'Code',// <- here
        qty: 'Qty',
    }
];
const doc = new jsPDF();
autoTable(doc, {
    head: head,
    body: someData,
    didParseCell: (hookData) => {
        if (hookData.section === 'head') {
            if (hookData.column.dataKey === 'qty') {
                hookData.cell.styles.halign = 'right';
            }
        }
    }
});
doc.save('fileName.pdf');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
var columns = [...];
var rows = [...];
var options = {
  headStyles:{
    valign: 'middle',
    halign : 'center'
  }
};
doc.autoTable(columns, rows, options);
doc.save('table.pdf');
```

Comment: How to align the specific header column of the PDF to the center in jspdf-autotable?                                   I want my 7th position header column aligned right and the others are the same as before